# Arraylist filter?

Tags: android

Android Development-ExpandableList(Headername,arraylist):

I have these two `arraylists headerArrayList<Category>` and `subHeaderArraylist<ItemDetails>.`

Category Class contains headerid, headername, Item Class contains headerid,subheadername;

Now, I need to filter out

if `headerid` of `headerArrayList` equals `headerid` of `subHeaderArraylist`, then result the `subheadername` of `subHeaderArraylist` ( which has same headerid).

My code:

```
    List<ItemDetail> result = new ArrayList<ItemDetail>();

        for(int i=0;i<headerArraylist.size();i++){
            Category cat =new Category();

        String category=headerArraylist.get(i).getHeader();
        String headeridd=headerArraylist.get(i).getHeaderid().trim();

            cat.setHeader(category);

            for (ItemDetail itemDetail : subheaderArrayList) {
                if (itemDetail.getHeaderid().toLowerCase().contains(headeridd.toLowerCase())) {

                    result.add(itemDetail);
                    cat.setItemList(filterlist);
                }

            }
            catList.add(cat);
```

Now i fill the `catList` to Expandable adapter:

```
 ExpandableListAdapter exAdpt = new ExpandableListAdapter(catList, this);
 exList.setAdapter(exAdpt);

         }
```

Lets say, `headerArraylist` contains `{(H0001,Cosmetics),(H0002,Snacks)}` and `subheaderArrayList` contains `{(H0001,Mens Cosmetics),(H0002,PotatoChips)}`.
When i tried to filter with `headerid=H0001`, it returns all `subheadername` viz Mens Cosmetics,Potatochips.

But, I did not get the output as expected as it returns all `subheadername`, not filtering out. Kindly suggest me what could have been wrong.

Comment: can you mention more code where these all things coming from?

Comment: Below is my whole code:

Comment: I have filled the two list headerArraylist and subheaderArraylist from sql server. Now inorder to fill the expandablelist we need to fill the adapter with another list catList which contains headername and list result. But i need to filter the only list that contains headerid of headerArraylist in subheaderlist. I tried with for loop with subheaderArraylist size.
But it results all the headername of subheaderArrayList and not filtered. thats the issue.

Comment: Below is my code sequence: catList = new ArrayList<Category>();
        fillheaderData();
        fillsubheader();
        fillExpandableData();--thats the part of the code I have submitted.

Comment: can you show your adapter class

Comment: Category Model Class- 
public class Category implements Serializable {
 private String headerid;
    private String header;
    private List<ItemDetail> itemList = new ArrayList<ItemDetail>();
}

ItemDetail Model Class:

public class ItemDetail implements Serializable {
    private String headerid;
    private String subheader;
}

Comment: Please mention in your question

Comment: Expandable List adapter link--> https://github.com/survivingwithandroid/Surviving-with-android/blob/master/ExpandableListView/src/com/survivingwithandroid/expandablelistview/ExpandableAdapter.java

Comment: result.add(itemDetail);
  cat.setItemList(filterlist);       the filterList shuld be result arraylist. in the question part..my mistake..

Comment: Read carefully this link : http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.com/2012/07/android-expandable-listview-simple.html

Comment: I have read i and implemented with their static arraylist assignments ,  the only difference is that their arraylist is static, assign in mainactivity,  and my arraylists are dynamic ie fetch from sql server.  Now my only issues is in inner for loop that returns all rows from subheaderarraylist. Thanks.